# Passing a preprocessed value to a Restcontroller in Spring/Boot with Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, kotlin

I am just starting out with Spring/Boot and Java/Kotlin in general. My task is to retrieve a HTTP ressource which returns JSON as string, to process that data and to direct it via Spring/Boot Restcontroller as response of an API call.

I want to retrieve the JSON string only once on startup, not every time I connect a client to the API. My question now is: How would I ideally make that data available to the RestController?

**My findings of maybe viable solutions so far:**

1. Enrich the request body off the API call with the data
2. @Autowire a class and data type as a dependency

In Javascript I'd simply pass it along as a parameter or would define the data object in a higher scope - for the sake of simplicity. Is that possible here, too?

**Example:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val data = RetrieveTheJSONDataOnce()
  runApplication<Demo>(*args)
}

@SpringBootApplication
class Demo

@RestController
class SpecificDataController {

  @RequestMapping(path = ["/"])
    fun doSomeDataMagic() : String {
      /* HOW WOULD I IDEALLY ACCESS "data" HERE? */
      return "Some String with processed data."
    }
}
```

Comment: Let the RestController initially retrieve the JSON resource?

Comment: In my understanding that would create unneccessary network traffic everytime a client hits the API since the data does not change much. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: You don't have to fetch it for *every* request. But only once

Comment: Create a `@Configuration` class whose constructor (or a `@PostConstruct` method) retrieves the data, holds it in a property, and then exposes that property or a getter method.  `@Autowire` an instance of that class wherever you need access to the data.

Comment: Thank you @gidds - I will use that as a starting point to learn how it works. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The main topic my problem related to is *Dependency Injection* in Spring/Boot. There are a lot examples on the web since it's one of the basic concepts of Spring/Boot but diving right in without knowledge of Java/Kotlin or how Spring worked *before* Boot was a bit difficult for me.

With the hints of @gidds I was able to come up with the following solution which works fine so far and hopefully helps other newbies to get a grasp of what is going on.

Basically Spring/Boots scans the whole project for Components and makes them available for everything else, incl. providing getters and setters. This is a lot less boilerplate, but also a bit more difficult to understand where things connect.

---

```
// add annotation @ComponentScan to your Spring/Boot application
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
class ExampleApp

// add annotation @Component to the class you want to be injected
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class ExampleComponent {
  val exampleValue : String = "Test"

  init {
    println("$exampleValue stuff happens once.")
  }
}

// provide the receiving class with injection parameter
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
class ExampleController( val exampleComponent : ExampleComponent) {

  @RequestMapping(path = ["/"])
  fun testResponse() : String {
    return exampleComponent.exampleValue
  }
}
```

Do not forget to add your custom package name `package com.demo.example` if you are going to split up the code into different files. Otherwise ComponentScan won't pick up those components.